# how to select specific parts of HTML through css or jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'd like to show specific parts of an HTML part. For example,

```
<html>
    <div class="entry">
        <span class="headword">work</span>
        <span class="synonym">job</span>
        <span class="antonym">play</span>
        <span class="subentry">
            <span class="headword">working</span>
            <span class="synonym">studying</span>
            <span class="antonym">playing</span> 
        </span>
    </div>
</html>
```

I need to hide all but the descendants of the element with `class="subentry"`.

Comment: `$(".entry").hide(); $(".subentry").show();` doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

**CSS**

```
.entry > span {
         display:none /*This hides all the direct child(span) of the parent div*/
         }
.entry .subentry { display:block}
```

​**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/N5mxW/2/)**

---

In case if you are using different tags in side the parent div then use `visibility`option.

**HTML**

```
<div class="entry">        
        <span class="antonym">play</span>
        **<span class="subentry">
            <span class="headword">working</span>
            <span class="synonym">studying</span>
            <span class="antonym">playing</span> 
        </span>**
    <div>sgnmgasd</div>
    <p>afs</p>
    </div>​
```

**CSS**

```
.entry{
 visibility:hidden
}
.subentry{
 visibility:visible
}
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/N5mxW/5/)**
​

Comment: Thanks, but in the real html file, there're more tags that shouldn't be displayed except the child of entry tag. I need to hide all except the embedded tags the entry tag includes.

Comment: I need them to be hidden, not invisible. But anyway, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

check this:

> http://jsfiddle.net/FL7kF/

```
$(".subentry").siblings().hide();
```

This will show only .subentry child spans while others will be hidden;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.subentry').siblings().hide()
```

This would hide all but the descendants of subentry tag. For more information on `siblings()` refer to [this](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

Answer (score 0):

did you mean you need to hide everything in entry except the 'subentry' part

That Id do this `$(".entry").hide()`

Then below it add `$(".subentry").show()`